# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am getting an error `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple` many times tried different ways from the internet nothing worked. Could anyone help me with this problem.

Here is my template part in settings.py file :

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR / 'templates'),
                 )
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIRS,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This line seems to be the problem

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR / 'templates'),)
```

`DIRS` is looking for a list, not a list of tuples, so instead you can use

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

Or if you want to keep your way:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR / 'templates'),]
```

and then set `DIRS` to

```
'DIRS': TEMPLATE_DIRS,
```

Comment: Then I get **expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list**

Answer (score 1):

Set template directory to:

```
'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
```

If it doesn't run, set to `BASE_DIR/ "templates"`

Answer (score 0):

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR / 'templates'),
```

I think the correct statement for this is :

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
```

and then place this in `TEMPLATES` list as the value for `DIRS`

another method is simply put `(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),` on `TEMPLATES` list

Answer (score 0):

`TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR / 'templates'),` in your example looks wrong - the `/` already does the `.join`, I believe. With `BASE_DIR` being a `Path()`, I would change this line to the following:

```py
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'templates']
```

However, are you sure `TEMPLATE_DIRS` is (or maybe now was) the issue and not some other path somewhere in your `SETTINGS`?

I've just upgraded to Django 4.1 and in my case, changing `MEDIA_ROOT` solved it. It was a tuple with just 1 element and probably should never have been a tuple to begin with, but it worked without issues for many years. But now I suddenly got exactly this error as well.