# Django TypeError at admin: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not PosixPath

Tags: python, django

Currently I just moved my django project to a new ubuntu server. But when I tried to access the admin website, it always return "`TypeError at /admin/: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not PosixPath`". The environment of my previous server is: Python3.6.9 and django 3.0.4. The current versions are Python 3.8 and Django 3.2.5. Are there any changes after the version update?

The `settings.py` is:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'XXXX'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'MyBlog',
    ...

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'MyBlog.context_processor.Alert_stat',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'MyBlog.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'myweb',
        'USER':'root',
        'PASSWORD':'112321',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'3306',
        'OPTIONS':{'charset':'utf8mb4'},
    }
}

...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
)]

#templates dirs
TEMPLATES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'))

#Media dirs

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the errors are induced by the version differences between Django 3.2.5 and Django 3.0.4. The main issues come from the path settings in `settints.py`. If someone faces the similar problems maybe these Q&As will be helpful:

[Django TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64634674/django-typeerror-argument-of-type-posixpath-is-not-iterable)

["TypeError at / argument 1 must be str, not PosixPath" in django ecommerce website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65219626/typeerror-at-argument-1-must-be-str-not-posixpath-in-django-ecommerce-websi)

[TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63982365/typeerror-expected-str-bytes-or-os-pathlike-object-not-tuple-in-django)

My solution is to downgrade django to 3.0.4.